# MYSQL how to select the highest value in column if the value is mixed with string

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to select the highest value from a column in order to generate a serial number. The problem is that column is mix of string and number value so I'm not getting the highest numeric value from my query because the column is a mix of string and numeric value.
The table is mix of `auctions` and `shipments` so the column is shared for both of them.
if I generate a auctions serial number i add A in front of it and if i generate shipment i generate S in front of it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEAIc.jpg

my query

```
SELECT AuctionSerialNumber AS serialCount
    FROM auctions
    ORDER BY AuctionSerialNumber DESC LIMIT 1
```

the function that gets the highest serial number and increment it by 1

```
let serialCount = results2[0].serialCount;
serialCount = serialCount.replace(/[AS]/g, '');
let tempSerialNumber = parseInt(serialCount, 10);
let nextSerial = tempSerialNumber + 1;
nextSerial = 'S' + nextSerial;
```

how to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you mean you are storing the `S1000` and `A1299` into the `AuctionSerialNumber` column in the database?

Comment: yes but the format looks like this S1234573 (you can see in the images i added)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does rather show what a bad idea it was to mix numbers and text in the same column.

It would have been better to put the int and char parts in 2 seperate columns.

Now you will need to do something to chop up that field and seperate the parts so you can do a proper sort. Something like this for example

```
SELECT right(AuctionSerialNumber,length(AuctionSerialNumber)-1) as serialCount
FROM auctions
ORDER BY cast(right(AuctionSerialNumber,length(AuctionSerialNumber)-1) as unsigned) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The `right(AuctionSerialNumber,length(acode)-1)` should see `S1234573` and return just `1234573` i.e just the number part, so you no longer need the regex in the other code, so you can remove this line

```
serialCount = serialCount.replace(/[AS]/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You May do with combination of sql function something like -

```
SELECT CONVERT(SUBSTR(AuctionSerialNumber,2,LENGTH(id)-1),unsigned INTEGER),AuctionSerialNumber
 FROM auctions
ORDER BY CONVERT(SUBSTR(AuctionSerialNumber,2,LENGTH(id)-1),unsigned INTEGER) desc
limit 1
```

Hope this helps you in your function code.

fiddle:
 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f0553/6

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using both values in a single column. maybe it will make sense.
so need to apply sorting techniques on complete data.

```
select *,RIGHT(AuctionSerialNumber, length(AuctionSerialNumber)-1),left(AuctionSerialNumber, 1) from test_temp order by RIGHT(AuctionSerialNumber, length(AuctionSerialNumber)-1),left(AuctionSerialNumber, 1) asc
```

Comment: please check with your tables structure.